# How to replace windows blink cursor shape?

Tags: windows, cursor

**How to replace windows blink cursor shape with some other?**

Example: I want to change it to brief cursor shape (which is type of blinking cursor which blink horizontal not vertical as is default in windows), that look like cursor in cmd.

OS: Windows 7

Comment: Do you mean in cmd.exe?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes like in cmd.exe

Comment: Use a [a different console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440269/whats-a-good-alternative-windows-console)?

Comment: @martineau I need to change blink cursor in all windows not only in one program

Comment: I see you asked this over in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439717/how-to-change-windows-blink-cursor-shape-from-c) as well. If at all this is possible (and I'm not sure it is), you'd probably require a program that runs constantly in the background. All Windows allows by default is changing the cursor's thickness via Ease of Access Center (type "Optimize visual display" in the Start Menu search box).

Comment: @Karan thnx for comment ... it don't have to be application which work in background to change blink cursor you can just replace .ico from some .dll where blink cursor appear (i didn't it yet), but if needed you can always use autohotkey, thnx for pointing me ....

Comment: Yeah, see I'm not entirely sure it's as simple as that. If it was just an ICO, how is Windows able to adjust the width on demand? Surely it doesn't store one ICO each per cursor width required - that would be ridiculous. I might be wrong, but I think that this particular blinking text cursor is generated dynamically by the OS, which is why it might not be so simple to override it.

Comment: yes you have right finally i find right function to create cursor (caret) [CreateCaret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648399(v=vs.85).aspx) but didn't test it thnx